# It is safe to push_back on a 2D vector on threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, vector

Lets say I have a 2D array and this function:

```
void addVec(std::vector<std::vector<short> >& arr, size_t idx){ 
   arr[idx].push_back(idx);
}

std::vector<std::vector<short> > arr(2);
boost::threads th1(addVec, boost::ref(arr), 0);
boost::threads th2(addVec, booost::ref(arr), 1);
th1.join();
th2.join();
```

By now I should have arr[0][0] = 0; and arr[1][0] = 1;
The questions is if this is safe? 
Internally the threads should add values to different parts of vector memory, and because it is constructed at the beginning of size 2 only the internal vectors get resized, witch have thread exclusive access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe in your use case, because you don't modify the shared data. However, I would prefer to pass the reference to the `std::vector<short>` to each thread to simplify the usage:

```
void addVec(std::vector<short> & arr)
{ 
   arr.push_back(some_data);
}

std::vector<std::vector<short> > arr(2);
boost::threads th1(addVec, boost::ref(arr[0]));
boost::threads th2(addVec, booost::ref(arr[1]));
th1.join();
th2.join();
```

Comment: Great, a good idea, I only wrote this way because I was thinking to a bigger algorithm that checks some numbers and appends them to vector by some criterion. But sometimes this main vector must be resized too witch I need to proetect everything with a mutex when one thread is making this operation.

Answer (score 4):

This should be safe since each thread accessing a separate vector. If however you do anything that might cause `arr` to resize, then all bets are off...

Comment: yes no resize in this form, but I was thinking in the next step to protect the resizing of the first vector with a mutex to grant exclusive access so I could advance this simple algorithm to resize as needed.

Comment: @palax If you protect the outer vector with a lock, you will have to get the lock in `addVec` too, since otherwise you might `push_back` on a vector that has moved. And then you've lost your concurrency. Just use two separate `vector` instances.

Comment: yes, I'm grateful that you thought trough my idea with the mutex. I did this yesterday and reached the same conclusion. my only solution was to leave the first vector intact.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest that you take a step back and consider what your goal is, before you continue down the path you are on.

First off, why do you want to parallelize your code? I assume you want your program to run faster. That means

1. You should start by writing a working sequential implementation.
2. You should profile and tune that implementation.
3. If (and only if) your program is still too slow for your purpose you should parallelize it if:

   1. A large part of the program can be parallelized (check out [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)).
   2. Your sequential implementation makes good use of the [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).
      The cache is very likely to be a bottleneck even for sequential code, so if your
      code isn't cache-efficient it will probably be slower when you parallelize it.

Points 1. and 2. is probably where you should be devoting your time. Odds are that a highly tuned sequential implementation is more than adequate for your needs and it will be *much* cheaper/easier/faster to develop and maintain.

If you do decide to parallelize your code, you should take a look at [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP). Threads are probably one of the worst ways to write parallel programs known to man. You may think that OpenMP's runtime system is too slow for you but again, you should take a step back and think about why.

If your algorithm requires a lot of locks and barriers, you can get a minor speedup by using faster locks and barriers. If you improve your algorithm to use fewer locks and barriers, you can achieve a much larger speedup.

Comment: I totally agree. But my current project is using voxel that requires a lot to be processed and made ready for the opengl. Voxels are split into chunks. As those chunks are unrelated to their neighbours so they can be paralelized to one thread per block. I made a timing check, look at this outcome: for adding 10 voxels on single core it took roughly 11 microseconds, adding 10 voxels on multicore took 14000 microseconds.  But adding 1000000 on singlecore took 100000, and adding 1000000 in multicore took only 17000. This is one of few examples that I think it will benefit from multicores.

Answer (score 2):

This is safe, although from a design point of view, it would be safer to give each thread only its inner vector, so there is less chance for future unsafe behavior